# RavenDB modelling 1 to many documents

Tags: c#, ravendb

Take this example model:

```
public class Location
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The relationship between these documents is a location can have none or many activities. Say London can have Paintball, Go karting etc.

I did thing to put these documents into one document but watching and reading the documentation and blogs, the documents need to be accessed separately. You can imagine a website page for each location listing activities and activity pages giving the details.

Example queries would be:

- Fetch all locations
- Fetch a locations details (given Location name from URL)
- Fetch all activities per location (given Location name from URL)
- Fetch an activities details (given Location name & Activity name from URL)

Using the DenormalizedReference method described at:

http://blogs.sonatribe.com/wayne/2011/07/06/using-denormalized-references-in-ravendb/

(and I did see this but couldn't figure out the syntax or if it does what I need

http://ravendb.net/faq/denormalized-references
)

Seems to kind of fit my scenarios. But when making a demo project with the above types I noticed if I changed a location name it didn't change it in the activity. Keeping the documents in sync is a big thing.

So how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phil,

- have a string LocationId property in the Activity, that would allow you to query for them.
- it would be easier probably to just store the activities as a collection inside the Location (so they aren't a separate document, but are embedded inside).

Comment: I did consider storing activities inside locations, but, that would mean I would have problems when the user wants to just view one activity at the location (the whole document would be returned).

Comment: When you say "query for them" could you link to how I would do this in RavenDB. I could see in a RDBMS using joins etc but unsure in RavenDB. For example, if I just wanted "Paintballing" from the "London" location document, wouldn't it return the whole London document?